# Scan and Print a string

Tags: c, c-strings

Ive written a very basic code and cant seem to get it to work.

```
char *a;
scanf("%s",a);
printf("%s",a);
```

Input: aWord

Output: Null

Where am i wrong here?Why am i getting null output?
I tried doing the following and it works as expected, why is it the case?

```
char a[50];
scanf("%s",a);
printf("%s",a);
```

Input: aWord

Output: aWord

I thought declaring a string in c using either of the above ways was equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *a;
```

Here, `a` is just a pointer of type `char*`. It points to some "random" location. There isn't any memory allocated to it. Writing to this invalid memory location invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can write to this location only if

1. Memory for `a` is allocated dynamically using `malloc`/`calloc`.
2. `a` points to a valid memory location:

   ```
   char buffer[100];
   a = buffer;

   // Now you can write to `a`.
   ```

Here:

```
char a[50];
```

memory is automatically allocated for `a` on the stack. So, you can write to this memory location.

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR**  -- Your First code snippet produces [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), your second code snippet is valid.

**Case 1:**

```
char *a;
scanf("%s",a);
printf("%s",a);
```

Here, `a` is uninitialized. Using that in `scanf()` invokes UB.

**Case 2:**

```
char a[50];
scanf("%s",a);
printf("%s",a);
```

here, `a` is properly allocated memory(at the compile time itself). So, it can be used safely with `scanf()`.

However, i'll suggest to use like

```
scanf("%49s",a);
```

to avoid the possible memory overflow.

Comment: So how do i correct my problem? The string that will be entered can range from 1 to 10000 characters and i dont want to waste space by defining it like: `char a[10000]`.